# Contao Navigation Icon/image

Tags: navigation, contao

I am having a hard time creating a simple way to replace one of my navigation menu with an icon or image.

The case is I have a text navigation and I want to add one more navigation menu with an icon or images.

| Home | Something | something | {images/icon} } |

just as simple as that.

What I have done : 
-create an :after css class with "background: url(..)" but broke up the whole navigation system,
 - install navigation images extension but doesnt work
 - create my own module with an image and put it into navigation menu like {{module:1}} but also doesn't work

So, guys let me know if you have something that I can work with. 
Remember, it is CONTAO Navigation system.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. For example, give the page that should be represented by an icon a unique CSS class in the site structure. Then you can use CSS to style that one menu item easily.

Alternatively, you can check for that CSS class in your `nav_default` template and create a different output just for that menu item.

Comment: That's right. In many cases you don't need extensions in Contao. Knowing about the additional CSS classes in the site structure, articles, elements and modules gives you maximum flexibility.